# Modify List within foreach loop with value from another list

Tags: c#, list, foreach

I am looping through a list and insert these values into another object. However I have another list and if `inv.id` and `inv.name` match I need to update the `amount` and `qty` with the values from the other list. What is best approach?

```
//loop through Invoices

 foreach (invoice inv in list1)
 {

//if id and name match my other list(list2) I need to replace inv.amount and inv.qty with the values from the other list (list2.amount, list2.qty)

InsertAdditionalInvoice(inv.ID, inv.name, inv.address, inv.lot, inv.order,   
inv.invoiceid, inv.amount, inv.qty);

 }
}
```

it is not updating the values in the first list. I have a method that returns the list then call it with following code:

```
var list2 = GetInivoice2();
```

I then call this list as follows in the foreach loop:

```
var listtmp = list2.FirstOrDefault(o => o.ID == inv.ID && o.name == inv.name );
if (listtmp != null)
{
req.Quantity = Convert.ToDouble(listtmp.Quantity);
```

here is list method that returns my list(names are different):

public List GetInvoice2()
        {

```
        List<inv2> inv2s = new List<inv2>();
        Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("tmp");


        DbCommand cmd = db.GetStoredProcCommand("getinv2");


        using (IDataReader reader = db.ExecuteReader(cmd))
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                inv2.Add(new inv2
                {
                    InvoiceID = Convert.ToInt32(reader["InvoiceID"]),
                    InvoiceName = reader["InvoiceName"].ToString(),
                    Quantity = Convert.ToDecimal(reader["Quantity"]),

                });
            }
        }
        return inv2;

    }
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Well, if you need to find some values in another list, then search them!

Answer (score 1):

This one will work i think

```
//if id and name match my other list(list2) I need to replace inv.amount and inv.qty with the values from the other list (list2.amount, list2.qty)
var q = list2.FirstOrDefault(o => o.ID == inv.ID && o.name == inv.name);
if (q != null)
{
    inv.amount = q.amount;
    inv.qty = q.qty;
}
```

Add above codes before calling InsertAdditionalInvoice. I'm not sure if this is the best approach or not, but i usually do it this way.

Comment: or just:  var q = list2.FirstOrDefault(o => o.ID == inv.ID && o.name == inv.name);

Comment: it is not updating the values in the first list. I have a method that returns the list then call it with following code: var list2 = GetInivoice2(); I then call this list as follows in the foreach loop:  var listtmp = list.FirstOrDefault(o => o.ID == inv.ID && o.name == inv.name );
                      if (listtmp != null)
                      {
                          req.Quantity = Convert.ToDouble(listtmp.Quantity);
                
                      }

Comment: if you set breakpoint inside if(q != null), is your program ever hit the breakpoint?

Answer (score 0):

Straight solution:

```
var l2value=list2.FirstOrDefault(l=>l.id==inv.id)
if(l2value!=null){
    inv.amount=l2value.amount;
    Inv.qty=l2value.qty;
}
```